Reverse List React-virtuoso
I'm trying to create a chat and want to use React-Virtuoso, but I'm having trouble setting the reverse direction of the container (similar to flexDirection: column-reverse).
The usual list of messages:
return (
    <Box sx={{ p: "12px 16px 8px", height: "100%", width: "100%" }}>
      <Virtuoso
        reversed={true}
        data={messages}
        endReached={handlePagination}
        className={styles.messagesList}
        itemContent={(_index, message: IMessage) => (
          <MessageCard key={message.id} message={message} />
        )}
        components={{
          EmptyPlaceholder: () => (
            <ListText>

How can I do this? I tried to put the attribute and expand it through styles
we expanded the list and the message via scale(-1), but it seems to me a strange solution
